# Get default field value on vf page

Tags: apex, visualforce, sobject, fields, describesobject

I am trying to get the default value of field but an error is coming.

```
List<String>apiNames =  new list<String>();
for(string apiName : des.fields.getMap().keySet()){
    apiNames.add(apiName);
    taskFieldCreation.apiName = Task.apiName.getDescribe().getDefaultValue();
 }
```

> Error: Compile Error: Invalid field apiName for SObject Task

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the field tokens, not the API Name, which is just a string. Also, you need to use SObject.put in order to set a dynamic field to a value, instead of the usual dot notation.

This should work:

```
Map<String, SObjectField> taskfields = des.fields.getMap();
for(String apiName: taskfields.keySet()) {
    SObjectField field = taskfields.get(apiName);
    apiNames.add(apiName);
    taskFieldCreation.put(field, field.getDescribe().getDefaultValue());
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.
SObject field = taskfields.get(apiName); error is coming on this line
Error: Compile Error: Illegal assignment from Schema.SObjectField to SObject

Comment: @Anzar, The error is descriptive enough, change declaration `SObject field` to `SObjectField field`. I think it is a typo.

Comment: @Anzar I apologize, it was indeed a typo. Changing it as I've just edited into the answer should fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> mapFields = 
    Schema.SObjectType.Task.fields.getMap();
for(string apiName : mapFields.keySet()){
    // default value
    System.debug(mapFields.get(apiName).getDescribe().getDefaultValue());
}
```